# Python Beautiful Soup Syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, beautifulsoup

I am looking for ways to simplify my beautiful soup code.

Normally while parsing I could do this:

```
content = soup.find_all('li')
links_from_content = content.find_all('a')
```

is there a way to do this single line? Something like:

```
content = harpatchnumber.find_all('li').find_all('a')
```

this seems to not be working so, I would like to know how i could do it better

Comment: Are you trying to find all `<a>` elements contained in all `<li>` elements? Just use an XPath expression.

Comment: you should post html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
soup.select('li a')
```

this will return a list of `a` tag which is contained by `li` tag

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for but it helped me get to where I wanted. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a single line with a list comprehension.

```
atags = [t.a for t in s.find_all('li') if t.a != None]
```